# Using Session code instead of PHP SELECT WHERE function

Tags: php, mysql

Since my question may be unclear:

in short I am wanting to make the following code shorter and/or faster

I have login system that starts a session and runs until you logout

I also have a SELECT WHERE script that counts how many invoices have not been paid that is working just fine but is long, ugly, and bulky like so:

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("REMOVED FOR SECURITY");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mypanda_invoices
WHERE is_paid='0'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<span class='badge badge-important'>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</span>";
  }
?>
```

Right now to get the users username I have: `<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` is there someway I could do this same type of thing with the code I have above? Just to make it shorter and take advantage of the session??? Thank you in advance.

Comment: if your MySQL table doesn't update frequently then you can use Query-cache for this. This will make your query faster.

Comment: I don't really understand where the `session` part comes into play here

Comment: I am wanting to use the `session` instead of that long code. In essence I am wanting to make the code shorter.

Comment: Well, you can store the result of this query (as it's actually a single number) in session. But you'll have to update it each time a record changes - which is not a small task. BTW, what's so 'long, ugly  and bulky' about this specific code?

Comment: I guess im just picky :) I Just liked the look of `<?php session_start();` rather than the long code. So are you saying the code I have used is the best option for something like this?

Comment: The approach - yes. The code still has some room for improvement. For example, I'd move all the db-initializing code into a separate function, and separated the querying code from the code that processed its result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the session has started, you can put the invoice count in the session as well.

If you want the code cleaner, I would recommend checking for a result set and then using `fetch_object()->inv_count` (or, in PHP 5.4, you could use `fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)[0]` I guess).

If you have an error with a vital part of your system -- the database connection for example, you should handle it gracefully (my `die` below isn't graceful, but it gets the job done) instead of just echoing and continuing on, which will result in a fatal error later on.

Also, using objects will make things a bit cleaner as well.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("REMOVED FOR SECURITY");

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());

$result = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS inv_count FROM mypanda_invoices
WHERE is_paid='0'");
if($result && $result->num_rows) $_SESSION['inv_count'] = $con->fetch_object()->inv_count;
    else $_SESSION['inv_count'] = 0;

echo "<span class='badge badge-important'>" . $_SESSION['inv_count'] . "</span>";
```